# What is Course Module instance / `$cm->instance`?

Tags: php, moodle

What does the `$cm->instance` refer to?
For example I know that `$cm->course` means the course id.
Thank you all.

```php
$cm = get_coursemodule_from_id('simplecertificate', $id);
if (!$cm) {
    print_error('Course Module ID was incorrect');
}

$course = $DB->get_record('course', array('id' => $cm->course));
if (!$course) {
    print_error('course is misconfigured');
}

$certificate = $DB->get_record('simplecertificate', array('id' => $cm->instance));
if (!$certificate) {
    print_error('course module is incorrect');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you have pasted in already shows exactly what $cm->instance is - it is the id of the record in the 'mdl_simplecertificate' database table that holds the details for this activity.

In general, $cm->instance is the id of the database table that stores the details for the type of activity the $cm refers to.

To find the type of activity in question, you need to get the value of $cm->module and look for an entry with that 'id' in the database table 'mdl_modules', the 'name' will give you the name of the activity type and, hence, the name of the database table that contains the instance data for that activity type.

So, if $cm->module points at the 'forum' entry in mdl_modules, then $cm->instance refers to the record with that id in table mdl_forum.

If $cm->module points at the 'assign' entry in mdl_modules, then $cm->instance refers to the record with that id in the table mdl_assign.

In this case, $cm->module will point at the 'simplecertificate' entry in mdl_modules, so $cm->instance refers to the record with that id in table mdl_simplecertificate.

Some more details are in the Moodle docs at: https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Course_module